# What does a good P2P configuration look like for a public node?

Tags: node, public-node, config, p2p, configuration

I have the following P2P settings in my config file for my public nodes, it seems to be okay, and is bootstrapping from the foundation nodes but I am interested to hear if there could be any improvements.  Are there any additional settings that would make it work better?  Are the values entered sensible?

```
        "p2p": {
            "private-mode": false,
            "bootstrap-peers": [ "dubnodes.tzbeta.net ", "franodes.tzbeta.net ", "sinnodes.tzbeta.net" , " nrtnodes.tzbeta.net" ],
            "listen-addr": "0.0.0.0:9732",
            "limits": {
              "authentication-timeout": 5,
              "min-connections": 100,
              "expected-connections": 100,
              "max-connections": 500,
              "backlog": 20,
              "max-incoming-connections": 100
            }
          }
```

Comment: One note: by setting min_connections = expected_connections, you cause a certain calculation in the p2p code `step_min = (expected - min) / 3` to result in 0. (Search for `step_min` in the code.) It is not immediately clear to me whether this is troublesome, but it is an edge case... I could try to explain the apparent significance of min/expected/max in a specific question about them -- this question seems too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `./tezos-node config update --connections=300` to fix your config file, as Tom said, those numbers should not match. Then restart tezos-node. Make sure your firewall is open, and any routers are port-forwarding to port 9732. You should also enable the RPC while you are at it `config update --rpc-addr=127.0.0.1:8732` so that you can use other tools which interface with the node API.